# Change the background colour and hide the radio buttons within a particular divs when a checkbox is inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/murshid1988/aMyLb/) to my code.

Here, when the check box is unchecked I need to turn the back ground colour to white and hide the radio buttons.

Meanwhile when it is checked I want to show the background colour as the current one and show the radio buttons

```
 <div class="newsletter-box">
     <span class="bonus-credit-wrapper">
         <input id="bonus-credit-checkbox" name="bonus-credit-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" />
         <label for="bonus-credit-checkbox" class="bonus-credit-checkbox-label">Your bonus credits</label>

         <span class="bonus-credit-description">
             Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis
         </span>
     </span>

     <span class="newsletter-preference">
         <span class="newsletter-preference-text">I prefer for:
         </span>

         <span class="gender-radio">
             <input checked id="newsletter-male" name="newsletter-gender" type="radio">
             <label for="newsletter-male">Women</label>
         </span>
         <span class="gender-radio">
             <input id="newsletter-female" name="newsletter-gender" type="radio">
             <label for="newsletter-female">Men</label>
         </span>

  </span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And my solution ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMyLb/9/)):

HTML:

```
<div class="newsletter-box unchecked">
    ...
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#bonus-credit-checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $('.newsletter-box').toggleClass('unchecked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

CSS:

```
.unchecked {
    background: #fff;
}

.unchecked span.newsletter-preference { 
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This does exactly what you want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/aMyLb/5/**

```
$(function(){
$("#bonus-credit-checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(".gender-radio").hide();
        $(".newsletter-box").css("background-color", "#fff");
    }
    else{
        $(".gender-radio").show();
        $(".newsletter-box").css("background-color", "#f6f2ef");
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for all the folks with jQuery... here comes an CSS-only solution:

```
#bonus-credit-checkbox:not(:checked) ~ .newsletter-preference{
    display:none;
}
```

only works in modern browsers, don't fulfills your background-color requirement and you have to change your html a little as seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMyLb/12/) - as such not a real answer to your question, just a proof of concept. :-)

Comment: Notice how i did not downvote your answer even though its not 100% right. Its called tolerance

Answer (score 0):

CHECK OUT THIS SOLUTION.
[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aMyLb/10/)

THIS IS WORKING. You need to make the background of the main div white by default. Also you have to make the radio button div "**display:none;**".

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
    $("#bonus-credit-checkbox").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){  
            $('.newsletter-preference').hide();         
            $('div').css('background-color', '#fff'); 
        }
        else{
            $('.newsletter-preference').show();
            $('div').css('background-color', '#f6f2ef');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: visual effects should be done with css, not with jquery using css()! Just set classes within the js code

Comment: You may be right. But the OP has a tag "jquery" , and hence the JQuery solution sticks.

Comment: @BastianRang, Could you be kind enough and tell me from which article or reference you are quoting this rule?

Comment: nothing against using jQuery. but it is common sense to separate structure, style and programming as far as possible, so setting inline css with jQuery.css() is not suggestive

Comment: @BastianRang Obviously there is no such rule but I believe that is an optimal solution. The click event won't be captured unless you use javascript/jquery. So, what's wrong about using it to complete the job?

Comment: @Bastian Rang ,That's what you say. I want to see a creditable source.

Comment: @BastianRang you went through all that trouble. WOW! Check the solution that the OP has marked as ANSWER. You edited it yourself. how come you ignored the fact that the answer also uses jQuery.

Comment: there is a difference (THE difference) between using `jQuery.css()` and `jQuery.toggleClass()`!

Comment: What are you going on about. Both the solutions use Jquery. Now if you told me that you have a solution which uses only Css, i would say great. Both my solution and Philips use Jquery. So both the solution add an extra overhead of downloading the Jquery library. so what the difference?