# Making child contenet appear/dissapear in according the state change of a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

This is a continues question of **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920642/change-the-background-colour-and-hide-the-radio-buttons-within-a-particular-divs)**.
The earlier question was on check box. But then I changed the check box into radio buttons according to the requirements.

Now I need to show the child radio buttons and change the background colour when a mother radio button is in active state. Once it changes to inactive state I need to hide the child radio buttons and change the background colour to white as well.

**Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/murshid1988/5c9ar/2/) and the HTML code,**

**PS: Don't mind the class names.**

```
 <div class="newsletter-box unchecked">    
     <span class="newsletter-checkbox-wrapper">
         <input id="bonus-credit-checkbox" name="newsletter-checkbox" type="radio" value="" />
         <label for="bonus-credit-checkbox">Your bonus credits</label>

         <span class="bonus-credit-description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis
         </span>
     </span>

     <span class="newsletter-preference">
         <span class="newsletter-preference-text">I prefer for:
         </span>

         <span class="gender-radio">
             <input checked id="newsletter-female" name="newsletter-gender" type="radio">
             <label for="newsletter-female">Women</label>
         </span>
         <span class="gender-radio">
             <input id="newsletter-male" name="newsletter-gender" type="radio">
             <label for="newsletter-male">Men</label>
         </span>

     </span>    

 </div>

 <div class="newsletter-box-daily unchecked">

     <span class="newsletter-checkbox-wrapper">

         <input id="daily-checkbox" name="newsletter-checkbox" type="radio" value="">
         <label for="daily-checkbox">Offers of the day</label>

         <span class="daily-description">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
         </span>

     </span>

     <span class="newsletter-preference">
         <span class="newsletter-preference-text">I prefer for:
         </span>

         <span class="gender-radio">
             <input checked id="newsletter-female-daily" name="newsletter-gender-daily" type="radio">
             <label for="newsletter-female-daily">Women</label>
         </span>
         <span class="gender-radio">
              <input id="newsletter-male-daily" name="newsletter-gender-daily" type="radio">
              <label for="newsletter-male-daily">Men</label>
         </span>

     </span>    

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you

`$('.newsletter-box').change(function(){console.log('changed')})`

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: `$('.newsletter-box').change(function(){if($('input[name="newsletter-checkbox"]:checked').length > 0){console.log('checked')}
    })`

by checking status change of `radio` and if it's `checked` with function above you can do whatever you want afterword

Comment: My question is, why `$('#bonus-credit-checkbox').on('change', function () {
        $('.newsletter-box').toggleClass('unchecked', !$(this).prop('checked'));       
    });` isn't working?

Comment: sorry ,my bad , didn't understood your question , i need to recheck it

Comment: Thanks for your help. I kinda fixed it. I manually added the 'unchecked' classes to other radio buttons using javascript. :)

Answer (score 1):

I checked your FIDDLE.

HERE is my solution. Check it. Tell me what changes need to be done.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5c9ar/4/)

JQUERY

```
$('#bonus-credit-checkbox').on('change', function () {
    $('.newsletter-box').toggleClass('unchecked', !$(this).prop('checked'));


});
$('#daily-checkbox').on('change', function () {
    $('.newsletter-box-daily').toggleClass('unchecked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I kinda fixed it. I manually added the 'unchecked' classes to other radio buttons using javascript.